# Building a map with coloring condition

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am trying to build a choropleth that is not exactly a choropleth in dc.js. What I am trying to do is color the map base on coloring condition and ultimately this will interact with other charts and filters as well. My csv looks like this:

```
country,id,condition,value
AU,1,yes,19
US,2,no,23
US,2,no,30
US,2,no,4    
IN,3,yes,14
SG,4,yes,2
NZ,5,no,6
NZ,5,no,20
```

and this is my approach so far, producing the count of occurrences.

```
var ndx = crossfilter(data)
var countryDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d){
  return d.country
});

var colors = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(['yes','no']).range(["green","blue"])
worldMap.width(mapWidth)
.height(mapHeight)
  .dimension(countryDimension)
  .group(countryDimension.group())
  .projection(project)
  .colors(colors)
  .colorCalculator(function(d){
    return d ? worldMap.colors()(d) : '#d8d8d8';
  })
  .overlayGeoJson(geoJson.features, "id", function(d){
    return d.id;
  })
  .title(function(d){
    return 'Country: ' + d.key + '\nCondition: ' + d.value;
  });
```

I am quite new to this amazing world of d3 and dc.js. Although I have been reading the documentation and forums I cannot figure out how I could make it so that a map is drawn, and the countries with the condition 'yes' is colored green and countries with the condition 'no' is colored blue. So pretty much if i do console.log(d.value) it should return either 'yes' or 'no'. I don't get what I have to do with my 'group'.

Comment: Don't use the `colorCalculator`; that's deprecated and will break the color scale, which looks correct. Do you mean that each country will consistently have only yes or no as its `condition`? Or do you want to go with the majority? Finally, it looks like your `countryDimension` should use `country` not `pocc`.

Comment: Yes, so each country will have either yes or no as its condition. So country like 'SG' will be colored 'green' and 'NZ' will be colored 'blue' and when i hover over each country the tooltip should display `Country: SG Condition: yes`, so I assume `d.value` returns the condition yes or no.  And yes it was meant to be country not pocc. Thanks in advance Gordon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every country has the same value for `condition` every time it is listed in the data, then in some sense the data is [denormalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization). That's fine, because crossfilter works best with a single array of data.

Of course it means that the choropleth won't respond to brushing on other charts, since the value is not affected by how many rows are currently filtered. But it will be able to filter other charts.

#### Count yesses

There are a couple of ways to do this. One way to do it is to count the number of yesses, and set the value according the count:

```
var yesnoGroup = countryDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
    return d.condition === 'yes' ? 1 : 0;
});
worldMap.valueAccessor(function(kv) {
    return kv.value ? 'yes' : 'no';
})
```

#### Grab first value

However this would probably cause countries to turn blue when they are filtered out by the other charts. So you could also use a "grab first value and hold onto it" strategy like this:

```
var yesnoGroup = countryDimension.group().reduce(
    function(p, v) { // add
        return v.condition;
    },
    function(p, v) { // remove
        return p; // ignore remove event
    },
    function() { // initialize
        return null; // no value
    });
```

A little bit ugly and a weird way to use crossfilter, but that's just because crossfilter expects the data to have some effect on the reduced value, and it doesn't here.

### EDIT: Three states

Based on the conversation below, I understand you're actually looking for three states: no, zero, and yes. (This makes more sense than the solutions above, but I'll leave those for posterity.) Here are two completely different ways to solve the no/zero/yes problem.

Both of these solutions use the following three-way color scale:

```
var colors = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(['no', 'zero', 'yes']).range(["blue", "grey", "green"])
```

#### No/zero/yes as negative/positive numbers

This is clever and simple: we'll just count each no as `-1` and each yes as `+1`. If the sum is zero, we'll draw in grey. The only caveat here is if there are contradictions in the data, you could get a false zero. But that might be better than a false no or yes (?)

```
var nozeroyesGroup = countryDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
  return d.condition === 'no' ? -1 : d.condition === 'yes' : +1 : 0;
});
worldMap.valueAccessor(function(kv) {
    return kv.value < 0 ? 'no' : kv.value > 0 ? 'yes' : 'zero';
})
```

#### No/yes polarity

We could also remember a count and polarity separately. This is maybe safer but also maybe slower. (Not that you'd notice unless your data is huge.) It's a bit more complicated. Kind of a matter of preference.

```
var nozeroyesGroup = countryDimension.group().reduce(
    function(p, v) { // add
        if(p.polarity && p.polarity != v.condition)
            console.warn('inconsistent');
        p.polarity = v.condition;
        ++p.count;
        return p;
    },
    function(p, v) { // remove
        if(p.polarity != v.condition || p.count <= 0)
            console.warn('inconsistent');
        --p.count;
        return p;
    },
    function() { // initialize
        return {count: 0, polarity: null}; // no value
    });
worldMap.valueAccessor(function(kv) {
    return kv.value.count ? kv.value.polarity : 'zero';
})
```

Comment: Thankyou Gordon this seemed to do the trick for the coloring of the map. However of course clicking on certain countries filters other charts accordingly, but upon clicking on other charts, it does not filter out the map. I double checked all my dimensions and they are all different and correct.

Comment: Right, so I warned above. How would you like them to filter? When there are zero yesses left, it turns blue? Or grey? Maybe you want coloring as a majority of yesses or not? This is why I asked.

Comment: Pretty much I have another chart, a row chart which is made up of bars of `country` and the height of it is the `value`. If i click on a certain bar, say 'US' it should pretty much leave 'US' colored and everything else should be the color of an undefined region. So on my side, all 'yes' countries are green, 'no' countries are blue and countries not included (undefined) are silver.

Comment: Aha, now we are getting somewhere. It's going to be in between these two approaches. I'll update my answer tomorrow, unless you figure it out before then.

Comment: It would also be great also if a `select` class appears on the country that is clicked and other countries that is not clicked to have a `deselected` class, so the row chart will mimic an on click event to the specific country on the map. But anything is fine, thankyou so much for all your help Gordon

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean the the classes, but I guess you mean that you'd like to link the map with a row chart so that they have the same selection, rather than just observing each other's filters. I think I've answered how to do that in another question (somewhere) and that's a feature which will arrive sometime in dc.js core in 2.1.*. Here I'll just focus on the crossfilter reduction problem, because it's better to keep each Q&A focused.

Comment: thanks so much Gordon, worked out well, thanks for all your help. I really appreciate it.